# Please help me solve this $x(\sqrt{2x+5}+\sqrt[3]{7x+13}) = 3x+6$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, problem-solving

Wolfram Alpha shows that the answer is $x=2\,$ and $x=-2\,$ but what would be the best way of simplifying this equation ? It has been many years since I was in school , and I just cannot wrap my head around it. :/

Comment: Thanks for fixing my mess of a equation gents, much appreciated

Comment: The standard trick is to bring all the terms which don't involve the cube root to one side and cube both the sides. Now bring all the square root terms to one side and square the whole thing. You are left with a polynomial some of whose roots are the roots of the original equations. Just plug in all the roots of the polynomial to see what works.

Comment: @Bolt64: "Just plug in all the roots": all eight of them? How do you find them all?

Comment: @TonyK Using the rational root theorem?

Comment: @TonyK, I think you actually get a polynomial of degree $9$, not $8$ (with a third real root less than $-5/2$).

Comment: @Ovi: Who says any of the roots are rational?

Comment: @TonyK Because the OP told us they are $2$ and $-2$ :P. Of course this approach doesn't always lead to a solution, but it is a possibility that should be checked (depending on the context, if this is a competition problem you probably shouldn't go down this route). Once $2$ and $-2$ are found this way, you can combine this with Roman83's argument and form a complete solution.

Comment: What makes you think you can just 'solve' this equation?  Sometimes, trial and error with some ability to guess is the best approach.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$x(\sqrt{2x+5}+\sqrt[3]{7x+13})=3x+6$$
$x\not=0$
$$\sqrt{2x+5}+\sqrt[3]{7x+13}=\frac{3x+6}x$$
$$\sqrt{2x+5}+\sqrt[3]{7x+13}=3+\frac6x$$

$x \in [-\frac52;0)\cup(0;+\infty)$

1) $x\in [-\frac52;0)$

Then $f(x)=\sqrt{2x+5}+\sqrt[3]{7x+13} -$ increasing function; $g(x)=3+\frac6x -$ decreasing function. Then $x=-2 -$ only root

2) $x\in (0;+\infty)$

Then $f(x)=\sqrt{2x+5}+\sqrt[3]{7x+13} -$ increasing function; $g(x)=3+\frac6x -$ decreasing function. Then $x=2 -$ only root

#### Addition:

Find the roots by hand and shows these two are the only roots. For example:

$$\sqrt[3]{x-2}+\sqrt{x-1}=5$$

Comment: This shows these two are the only roots, but how do you find the roots (by hand)? I suppose that's OP's main problem/question.

Comment: @StackTD: by hand.

Comment: This is great , thank you Roman83